# Permission denied pulling image from Red Hat Registry

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am installing an application using an operator in my Openshift 4.1 cluster that needs access to pull images from the Red Hat registry. When I run the install from my project, the operator tries to pull an image from the Red Hat registry and I get a permission denied.

```
>oc project 3scale
>oc import-image amp-apicast --from=registry.redhat.io/3scale-amp26/apicast-gateway --confirm

Unable to sync image for tag amp-apicast:2.6. Internal error occurred: Get https://registry.redhat.io/v2/3scale-amp26/apicast-gateway/manifests/latest: unauthorized: Please login to the Red Hat Registry using your Customer Portal credentials. Further instructions can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3399531
```

But when I pull the images manually from the Openshift project in my cluster my pull secret from my openshift-config project is picked up and it downloads the image successfully.

```
>oc project openshift
>oc import-image amp-apicast --from=registry.redhat.io/3scale-amp26/apicast-gateway --confirm
```

What is the best way to make give my project access to be able to download images from the Red Hat registry? As I understand it copying the pull secret to my project is not the way to go about it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to make give my project access to be able to download images > from the Red Hat registry? As I understand it copying the pull secret to my project is not the way to go about it.

If you can access here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3399531, then you had better to create registry credential secret through `Creating Registry Service Accounts` steps. Image pulling could be enabled in `openshift` because of the `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` type of registry credential secret.

```
e.g.>
# oc get secret -n openshift
NAME                       TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
imagestreamsecret          kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1         25d
...
```

That type of secret is used by image pull credential secret automatically if that type secret is existing in the same namespace.

Further information is here [Allowing Pods to Reference Images from Other Secured Registries](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#allowing-pods-to-reference-images-from-other-secured-registries)
 for manual configuration steps.

```
$ oc create secret generic <pull_secret_name> \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

After creating the credential secret in your namespace, try to execute `oc import-image`. For testing, you can also copy the secret in `openshift` to your namespace. I hope it help you.